# postgres lock rows in 2 tables

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I have a postgres 9.5 database. One application performs some action on `session` table. It updates one row in `session` table and insert N rows to `messages` table. Other application is trying to do the same, but those 2 apps are not connected with each other. How can I force app 2 to wait for it's action before app 1 action ends using postgres db? So I want only those 1 and 2 records be blocked and not to make any serious impact on performance. Or is there any other graceful way  to do that?

**UPDATE**

1. App1 runs select * from `session` where mode=5
2. App2 runs myUpdate(selected records) - in new transaction somewhere
3. App2 runs myUpdate(selected records - from other logic) - in new
   transaction

So basically I have 2 aps but 3 actions and all of them in 3 separate transactions. That's why I asked about postgres

Comment: Why not let postgres manage any concurrency?Seems a bad design somewhere if logically linked actions are not also linked in code.

Comment: As long as the first application doesn't commit the `update` the second application **will** wait when trying to update the same row.

Comment: Thank you guys, it was my mistake. I have 2 apps but they do 3 actions with the same (or intersected) records. First selects, second updates, third updates all in their own transactions

Comment: Then let App1 do a `select ... for update` to lock the rows.

Comment: Thanks, but what is select for update records will not be updated in the same transaction? What if rabbit consumer that updates it will fail and will not update them? Will they be locked forever?